# How to create an UI in circular fashion in Android?

Tags: android

[image]

I need to create a dynamic UI for an android app. For example, I need to create clickable buttons on the circumference of a circle with a main button at the center. The user should be able to add/delete/modify the number of nodes/buttons on the circumference of the circle with settings option.

Till now I have worked on static UI using xml layout. This time I have to start working dynamic model. How can I proceed?

Uploaded sample UI how I would like to build. As shown in figure I should be able to create a dynamic UI, user should be able to click on the boxes, should be able to add few more boxes which should auto adjust its position with respect to other boxes. When I click on the box it should bring another activity with different UI with the selected box populated to center surrounded by related data in similar format shown in figure.

Comment: no comments on the problem i pose!!!Is there any problem with the question???

Comment: How about an image of what you are proposing?

Comment: could you please give me an idea so I can starting working on that.

Comment: This is far too broad for Stack Overflow. Even when it was asked in 2012, when the rules were more lax, it was still a good idea to show users what research you had done prior to asking a question.